# How do I convert a Web API JSON response to a data table?

Tags: c#, xml, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API where if I go to a valid link, it'll display an XML.

However, in my other application, when I call:

```
using (var webclient = new WebClient())
{
    var doc = webclient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

It's returning JSON data.

How do I convert this JSON to a data table? OR, should I "de-serialize" this JSON so that it becomes an XML and then I can work with the XML in order to convert it to a data table?

Comment: Converting JSON to a dataTable doesn't make sense. If you know what the xml is, why not create objects that represent that xml and serialize the JSON to that?

Comment: brad, I was actually the one who created the API. The call to the API returns a SQL query result. It's a list of shows. I'm new to the company here and I'm getting my hands wet on all of the latest web technologies so they wanted me to do it this way. I created the API and now I need to create a web form which will consume the results of the API calls to that API (which is a list of TV shows). does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just go directly to `DataTable` with json.NET but I would recommend deserializing into other objects unless you have good reason to use a `DataTable` for example if the json is actually structure like a `DateTable` which isn't really normal. Json typically closely relates to native objects and in general, that's the best way to model it.

You can just use this method to deserialize it directly into a `DataTable`;

```
   DateTable myDataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

Should you choose to go the native objects route you can just define the objects in C# like you would any other (they need properties that exactly match those in the json), then call the same method except where I have `DataTable` you would instead use your type.

Comment: what kind of object do you recommend I de-serialize it to?

Comment: by the way, what reference do I need to add to my class in order to use JsonConvert? I already installed Json .NET.

Comment: Note that the line of code above will only work if the JSON you are using was a DataTable to start with and then serialized. You can't just take any JSON and plug it in there.

Comment: thanks, @JesseWebb. it WAS a database table before it was serialized so I think I should be good. I just need to know what assembly to reference in my class in order to use JsonConvert.

Comment: @Rj What does your JSON represent? Use that. For instance, if it is an array of People, each with a birthday: create a Person class with a Birthday property and deserialize into a List of those.

Comment: can anyone tell me what I assembly I need to work with JsonConvert? I can't move forward unless I figure that out :(